# Global scope for maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

Is is possible to use a plugin or some other mechanism to set all the dependencies of a maven module to a certain scope?
I have a lot of dependencies inherited, with different scopes and I need all of them to be 'compile'. 
I would avoid going to each declaration of dependency and add the scope...etc. I would prefer to be able to do this in a single line, at once, for all the dependecies together-globally, like 'set scope compile for all the inherited dependencies'.

Can you please give me a solution?

Thank you,
Roxana

**Late edit** I hope not:) it would be difficult to know this global setup when working in a low level artifact

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a parent pom you can define the scope of the dependency in the parent. You still need to specify the dependency in the child pom but its scope (and version) inherits from the parent.

Parent pom:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactID</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
```

Child pom:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifactID</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: my idea is not to control this from dependency management because I have a lot of depedencies and all of them have the same scope. I want to set this globally, at once, for all the dependencies.